# How to handle proptypes for image?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-proptypes

```js
AlertMessage.defaultProps = {
  icon: Images.promptWarning
};

AlertMessage.propTypes = {
  icon: PropTypes.node
};
```

```js
promptWarning: Platform.OS === 'android' ? { uri: 'asset:/some.png' } : require('../some.png'),
```

Due to unable to bundle assets in Release mode for android, the above approach was taken, by using `{ uri: 'asset:/some.png' }` instead of standard `require('../some.png')`, but now it raised another issue due to `propTypes` expecting PropTypes.node, whats the correct type that I should use for above case?

Comment: You can create separated components for each platform. It will be compiled separated: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code#platform-specific-extensions

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo: I dont really get your point, if possible do you mind to share the example on how it can be apply to `component.propTypes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
AlertMessage.propTypes = {
  icon: Platform.OS === 'android' ? PropTypes.shape({
    uri: PropTypes.string
  }) : PropTypes.node
};
```

Not sure if it's the right way but I do check within `propTypes` to decide which `PropTypes` to check against. Thanks @JoaozitoPolo for the idea